# Is it possible for extension-contributed snippets in VS Code to be updated dynamically?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to work on VS code snippet extension (like muiSnippets) for a component library. I have frequent version updates for the component library which changes code snippets, component list and related props/values.

To solve this I thought to store JSON of each version on server and load it in extension based on component library version.

Is it possible to change snippet.json content dynamically and support dynamic snippets?

I tried to load snippet from API and write in snippets.json file but it didn't worked.

Comment: can you please show your attempt? FWIW I just tried updating my _user_ snippets file (not an extension snippets file) outside of VS Code and saving, and VS Code picked up on the changes right away. So it seems that this is supported for user snippet files, but I don't know about extension snippet files. Have you verified that your writes to the file are succeeding and writing the content that you expect? Does the update get recognized after reloading VS Code?

Comment: To achieve this I did on folder change I read nearest package.json and read the version of needed package and I was trying to get updated snippets from server but my case was different I am creating extension for organisation package so I am storing snippets in build folder and reading it in extension so it saves API call and cache it on extension.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post. And it might help if you show the code for your attempt (see also the instructions for writing a [mre])